# PHP Link change in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Ok, so, I am working with a theme in Wordpress, I am trying to change a redirect link on the main page.

It goes to a link they created and I need it to go somewhere else. I believe I should be editing a PHP file (*wp-content\plugins\trx_addons\components\cpt\services\services.php* file) although I have not done this before.

Can I not just change the code elsewhere?

Here is the screenshot of the code when I inspect.

[image: code print screen]
I will assume If I was a trained within coding, I would change where it says Link. However - I think if I do this, within the theme template, how would I re-direct the link? Ugh, plugins.. and wordpress...

Here is the code within the Php File:

```
<?php
/**
 * The style "default" of the Services
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage ThemeREX Addons
 * @since v1.4
 */

$args = get_query_var('trx_addons_args_sc_services');
$number = get_query_var('trx_addons_args_item_number');

$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'trx_addons_options', true);
$link = get_permalink();
if (empty($args['id'])) $args['id'] = 'sc_services_'.str_replace('.', '', mt_rand());
if (empty($args['featured'])) $args['featured'] = 'image';
if (empty($args['featured_position'])) $args['featured_position'] = 'top';

$svg_present = false;
$price_showed = false;

if (!empty($args['slider'])) {
    ?><div class="slider-slide swiper-slide"><?php
} else if ($args['columns'] > 1) {
    ?><div class="<?php echo esc_attr(trx_addons_get_column_class(1, $args['columns'])); ?>"><?php
}
?>
<div class="sc_services_item<?php
    echo isset($args['hide_excerpt']) && $args['hide_excerpt'] ? ' without_content' : ' with_content';
    trx_addons_show_layout($args['featured']=='image' 
                        ? ' with_image' 
                        : ($args['featured']=='icon' 
                            ? ' with_icon' 
                            : ($args['featured']=='number' 
                                ? ' with_number' 
                                : '')));
    echo ' sc_services_item_featured_'.esc_attr($args['featured']!='none' ? $args['featured_position'] : 'none');
?>"<?php
    if (!empty($args['popup'])) {
        ?> data-post_id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>"<?php
        ?> data-post_type="<?php echo esc_attr(TRX_ADDONS_CPT_SERVICES_PT); ?>"<?php
    }
?>>
    <?php
    // Featured image or icon
    if ($args['featured'] != 'none') {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() && $args['featured']=='image') {
            trx_addons_get_template_part('templates/tpl.featured.php',
                                            'trx_addons_args_featured',
                                            apply_filters('trx_addons_filter_args_featured', array(
                                                                'class' => 'sc_services_item_thumb',
                                                                'hover' => 'zoomin',
                                                                'thumb_size' => apply_filters('trx_addons_filter_thumb_size', trx_addons_get_thumb_size($args['columns'] >= 2 ? 'medium' : 'med'), 'services-default'),
                                                                'post_info' => !empty($meta['price']) 
                                                                                    ? '<span class="sc_services_item_price">'.esc_html($meta['price']).'</span>'
                                                                                    : ''
                                                                ),
                                                            'services-default'
                                                            )
                                        );
            $price_showed = true;
        } else if ($args['featured']=='icon' && !empty($meta['icon'])) {
            $svg = $img = '';
            if (trx_addons_is_url($meta['icon'])) {
                $img = $meta['icon'];
                $meta['icon'] = basename($meta['icon']);
            } else if (!empty($args['icons_animation']) && $args['icons_animation'] > 0 && ($svg = trx_addons_get_file_dir('css/icons.svg/'.trx_addons_esc($meta['icon']).'.svg')) != '')
                $svg_present = true;
            ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>"
                 id="<?php echo esc_attr($args['id'].'_'.trim($meta['icon']).'_'.trim($number)); ?>"
                 class="sc_services_item_icon <?php
                        echo !empty($svg) 
                                ? 'sc_icon_type_svg'
                                : (!empty($img) 
                                    ? 'sc_icon_type_img'
                                    : esc_attr($meta['icon'])
                                    );
                        ?>"<?php
                 if (!empty($meta['icon_color'])) {
                     echo ' style="color:'.esc_attr($meta['icon_color']).'"';
                 }
            ?>><?php
                if (!empty($svg)) {
                    trx_addons_show_layout(trx_addons_get_svg_from_file($svg));
                } else if (!empty($img)) {
                    $attr = trx_addons_getimagesize($img);
                    ?><img class="sc_icon_as_image" src="<?php echo esc_url($img); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr__('image', 'jude'); ?>"<?php echo (!empty($attr[3]) ? ' '.trim($attr[3]) : ''); ?>><?php
                }
            ?></a><?php
        } else {
            ?><span class="sc_services_item_number"><?php
                printf("%02d", $number);
            ?></span><?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="sc_services_item_info">
        <div class="sc_services_item_header">
            <h4 class="sc_services_item_title<?php if (!$price_showed && !empty($meta['price'])) echo ' with_price'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>"><?php
                the_title();
                // Price
                if (!$price_showed && !empty($meta['price'])) {
                    ?><div class="sc_services_item_price"><?php echo esc_html($meta['price']); ?></div><?php
                }
            ?></a></h4>
            <!-- <div class="sc_services_item_subtitle"><?php trx_addons_show_layout(trx_addons_get_post_terms(', ', get_the_ID(), TRX_ADDONS_CPT_SERVICES_TAXONOMY));?></div> -->
            <div class="sc_services_item_button sc_item_button"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr(apply_filters('trx_addons_filter_sc_item_link_classes', 'sc_button sc_button_default sc_button_size_small sc_button_hover_slide_top', 'sc_services', $args)); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Book now', 'jude'); ?></a></div>
        </div>
        <?php if (!isset($args['hide_excerpt']) || $args['hide_excerpt']==0) { ?>
            <div class="sc_services_item_content"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <!-- <div class="sc_services_item_button sc_item_button"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr(apply_filters('trx_addons_filter_sc_item_link_classes', 'sc_button sc_button_simple', 'sc_services', $args)); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Learn more', 'jude'); ?></a></div> -->
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
if (!empty($args['slider']) || $args['columns'] > 1) {
    ?></div><?php
}
if (trx_addons_is_on(trx_addons_get_option('debug_mode')) && $svg_present) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'vivus', trx_addons_get_file_url(TRX_ADDONS_PLUGIN_SHORTCODES . 'icons/vivus.js'), array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'trx_addons-sc_icons', trx_addons_get_file_url(TRX_ADDONS_PLUGIN_SHORTCODES . 'icons/icons.js'), array('jquery'), null, true );
}
?>
```

If you cannot answer this - can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit is responsible for the link in that template:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr(apply_filters('trx_addons_filter_sc_item_link_classes', 'sc_button sc_button_default sc_button_size_small sc_button_hover_slide_top', 'sc_services', $args)); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Book now', 'jude'); ?></a>
```

You can see there is a PHP variable `<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>` going into the `href` which is where the link will go. If you change it to

```
href="WHATEVER_LINK_HERE"
```

...you may have your issue solved, however because it is a theme, if you ever update the theme you will lose this change

Comment: Thank you SO much for this! I see what you mean - I am not too worried about updating the theme - I won't even go there LOL! I am curious though, I created two of those classes - although the names of them are not there and they need to go two separate places. So I don't see how changing that one link would fix it - there are two links so I am kind of SOL. You know what I mean?